# Bootstrap button gets "stuck" in active when touched on Mobile, but not desktop. Vuejs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a basic bootstrap button with Vuejs. On click release I need button to go back to default. This works on Desktop but on mobile the button remains active. How can I trigger a touch release event in my triggerFunction() for it to go back to inactive.

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="triggerfunction()">MyButton</button>
```

Comment: How can i fixed this ?